# Creating normal noise array with different dispersions(sigma)

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

I have a problem where I need to create a numpy array 1920x1080 filled with a normally distributed noise and for each element I use different sigma (gradually incremented with step).
But I ran into a time problem: I creating around 1500 arrays(not at the same time but, writing first in file then creating second and writing it and so on) and time it cost is nearly 1.5 ours. I used folowing code

```py
np.fromiter((random.normalvariate(0, sigma_step * x) for x in range(0, 1080 * 1920)), dtype = np.float64).reshape(1080, 1920)
```

I'm thinking about creating 1500 values at once because they have same sigma value but calling np.random.normal 1080*1920 times dont give me <5 min mark and creates multiple storage problems(I need to write binary each frame consistently and dont have so much memory to keep them all)
Thanks for any help

Comment: You can pass an array for the `scale` parameter in `np.random.normal`. Simply populate that array with your sigma values.

Comment: Thank you. Now it only takes 2 minutes. I didn’t know that you could pass an array there

Comment: For 1920x1080 values? It shouldn't take two minutes, it should take less than a second.

Comment: I call this function around 1500 times and in total it costs 2 minutes so for one call it's less than a secon